# Rails - has many polymorphic tagging not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, tagging

I have two tables for tagging so that I can attach tags to any models, it works likes so…

There's a tagged item join table which has a tag_id column and then two other columns for polymorphism: taggable_type and taggable_id…

```
class TaggedItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :taggable_id, :taggable_type, :tag_id

  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

There's also all of the things that can have tags, for example here's a product and image model with tags attached:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_items, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :tagged_items
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_items, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :tagged_items
end
```

The problem is with the tag model, I can seem to get the reverse work, on the tag modle I want to have a has_many images and has_many products like so:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :tagged_items
  has_many :images, :through => :tagged_items
end
```

This is causing an error, I was wondering how I can fix this. So the tag table works through the polymorphic tagged items table.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

```
Could not find the source association(s) :product or :products in model TaggedItem. Try 'has_many :products, :through => :tagged_items, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :taggable or :tag?
```

Comment: What error is thrown? Can you post it? I.e., what happens when you do "some_tag.products"?

Comment: why you are using polymorphic on TaggedItem? Since no relation between one TaggedItem and other TaggedItem i.e. in TaggedItem; no has_many :tagged_items, :as => :taggable association.

Comment: @Stobbej I've put up the error you get if you do some_tag.products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has_many :through` associations in your Tag model are not able to get the source association for `Product` and `Image` from the `TaggedItem` Model. e.g. `has_many :products, :through => :tagged_items` will look for a direct association `belongs_to :product` in TaggedItem which in case of polymorphic association is written as `belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true`. So for the Tag model to understand exact source of the association we need to add an option `:source` and its type as `:source_type`

So change your Tag model associations to look like

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :tagged_items, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Product'
  has_many :images, :through => :tagged_items, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Image'
end
```

This should fix your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the `as` option when you set up the Tag association to TaggedItem.  `:as => :taggable` would mean that tag on tagged item is polymorphic which it is not. Instead the other side is, ie., the items that are taggable as your name cleverly suggests :).

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :tagged_items
  has_many :images, :through => :tagged_items
end
```